# React Testing: Event handlers in React Shallow Rendering unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, reactjs, mocha.js

## Background

[image: React Shallow Rendering tests]

I am trying to learn how to use the React Shallow Rendering TestUtil and had the tests passing until I added an `onClick` event handler to both; It seems that there must be some difference with the `Accordion.toggle` function I am trying to use in `Accordion.test.js` vs `this.toggle` in `Accordian.js`...but I can't figure it out.

## Question

How can I get the two highlighted tests in `Accordian.test.js` to pass?

## Steps to reproduce

1. Clone https://github.com/trevordmiller/shallow-rendering-testing-playground
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run dev` - see that component is working when you click "Lorem Ipsum"
4. `npm run test:watch` - see that tests are failing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of issues preventing your tests from passing.

Looking at the test "should be inactive by default":

1. `Accordion.toggle` in your test is a property of the `Accordion` class, and `this.toggle` in your code is a property of a instance of the `Accordion` class - so in this case you are comparing two different things. To access the 'instance' method in your test you could replace `Accordion.toggle` with `Accordion.prototype.toggle`. Which would work if it were not for `this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);` in your constructor. Which leads us to the second point.
2. When you call .bind() on a function it creates a new function at runtime - so you can't compare it to the original `Accordion.prototype.toggle`. The only way to work around this is to pull the "bound" function out of the result from render:

   ```
   let toggle = result.props.children[0].props.onClick;

   assert.deepEqual(result.props.children, [
     <a onClick={toggle}>This is a summary</a>,
     <p style={{display: 'none'}}>This is some details</p>
   ]);
   ```

As for your second failing test "should become active when clicked":

1. You try calling `result.props.onClick()` which does not exist. You meant to call `result.props.children[0].props.onClick();`
2. There is a bug in React that requires a global "document" variable to be declared when calling setState with shallow rendering - how to work around this in every circumstance is beyond the scope of this question, but a quick work around to get your tests passing is to add `global.document = {};` right before you call the onClick method. In other words where your original test had:

   ```
   result.props.onClick();
   ```

   Should now say:

   ```
   global.document = {};
   result.props.children[0].props.onClick();
   ```

   See the section "Fixing Broken setState()" [on this page](http://rackt.github.io/redux/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) and [this react issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4019).

Answer (score 3):

[Marcin Grzywaczewski](https://twitter.com/killavus) wrote a great [article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/approaches-to-testing-react-components-an-overview/) with a workaround for testing a click handler that works with shallow rendering.

Given a nested element with an `onClick` prop and a handler with context bound to the component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a className="link" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.linkText}
      </a>
      <div>extra child to make props.children an array</div>
    </div>
  );
}

handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ linkText: 'clicked' });
}
```

You can manually invoke the function value of the `onClick` prop, stubbing in the event object:

```
it('updates link text on click', () => {
  let tree, link, linkText;

  const renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
  renderer.render(<MyComponent />);

  tree = renderer.getRenderOutput();
  link = tree.props.children[0];
  linkText = link.props.children;

  // initial state set in constructor
  expect(linkText).to.equal('Click Me');

  // manually invoke onClick handler via props
  link.props.onClick({ preventDefault: () => {} });

  tree = renderer.getRenderOutput();
  link = tree.props.children[0];
  linkText = link.props.children;

  expect(linkText).to.equal('Clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing user events like `onClick` you would have to use `TestUtils.Simulate.click`. [Sadly](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/whats-the-prefered-way-to-test-react-js-components/26/17):

> Right now it is not possible to use ReactTestUtils.Simulate with Shallow rendering and i think the issue to follow should be: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1445

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully tested my click in my stateless component. Here is how:

My component:

```
import './ButtonIcon.scss';

import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const ButtonIcon = props => {
  const {icon, onClick, color, text, showText} = props,
    buttonIconContainerClass = classnames('button-icon-container', {
      active: showText
    });

  return (
    <div
      className={buttonIconContainerClass}
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{borderColor: color}}>
      <div className={`icon-container ${icon}`}></div>
      <div
        className="text-container"
        style={{display: showText ? '' : 'none'}}>{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonIcon.propTypes = {
  icon: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  color: React.PropTypes.string,
  text: React.PropTypes.string,
  showText: React.PropTypes.bool
}

export default ButtonIcon;
```

My test:

```
it('should call onClick prop when clicked', () => {
  const iconMock = 'test',
    clickSpy = jasmine.createSpy(),
    wrapper = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<div><ButtonIcon icon={iconMock} onClick={clickSpy} /></div>);

  const component = findDOMNode(wrapper).children[0];

  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(component);

  expect(clickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component).toBeDefined();
});
```

The important thing is to wrap the component:

```
<div><ButtonIcon icon={iconMock} onClick={clickSpy} /></div>
```

Hope it help!